# Weirdness with tags in the close queue

Tags: bug, review-queues

I'm experiencing something weird today when reviewing the close queue with a filter on `[postgresql]`.

Several times, I've stumbled on questions that seem to have that tag, despite having nothing to do with PostgreSQL. But when I'm opening a new window on the question to untag it, it appears that the question doesn't actually have that tag.

Example:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/12922589
currently displays (for me) `[postgresql] [perl]` as tags at the bottom of the question's text.
But the question itself:
[Looking to search for string in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733186/looking-to-search-for-string-in-text-file) shows only `[perl]` in the tags line.

I guess this could happen if someone just untagged it like as I was about to do, except that:

- I saw this on too many questions today (4 or 5)
- when reopening the page in the review queue in a different window, it still shows the `[postgresql]` tag.
- when reopening the page in the review queue in a different window in private browsing (no cookie, no login), **it doesn't show** the `[postgresql]` tag.
- when opening it in a different browser and without logging in to SO, **it doesn't show** the `[postgresql]` tag.
- when loging in with that other browser, and going to that page, it does show again the `[postgresql]` tag.

It's as if that tag came from the combination of my profile and this question, and only in the review queue, rather than just the question itself.
Is that a bug in the review queue, or is there another explanation?

Comment: That's normal for review audits.. The "fake" tag is from your filter. For example that review is tagged with [java] for me.

Comment: It is an audit success.  If you notice it then obviously you are paying attention.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the duplicate! Still I think it's really injudicious of the audit system to show questions like that. It moves the balance too far in wasting reviewer's time rather than just fighting robot-voting.